# EOS CDT: where are the *.h and the *.cpp files stored in the filesystem, I need reference to them to compile

Tags: ubuntu, c++, contract-development

I'm trying to use the EOS CDT (contract development toolkit).

I've downloaded and installed the repository from github, and used to following commands, as indicated from the eos.io development page.

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/installing-the-contract-development-toolkit

console commands:

```
wget https://github.com/eosio/eosio.cdt/releases/download/v1.3.2/eosio.cdt-1.3.2.x86_64.deb
sudo apt install ./eosio.cdt-1.3.2.x86_64.deb
```

I can't find the reference to the h and cpp files in ubuntut's (16.04.5) filesystem.
Where are they?

I need to reference them for compiling the test codes and the examples.
I'm also using visual studio code ide.

Answer (score 1):

using the command:

dpkg -c eosio.cdt-1.3.2.x86_64.deb

The folder where the files are installed are shown:

the CDT files are stored in /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/

Answer (score 0):

package name is `eosio.cdt` ( you can check by `dpkg -l | grep eosio.cdt` )

`dpkg --listfiles eosio.cdt`

you can see the files installed by that package